# Visual Studio 2019 XAML Designer does not display x64 User Controls from external projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having trouble viewing my custom user controls in the XAML Designer.

I have multiple custom WPF user controls from multiple different projects that I am loading into a WPF App window in a separate project. I am able to create them in the XAML code but they only show up as blank outlines in the designer. There are no errors, and when I build and run the WPF application the user controls show up properly.

This is only happening with WPF user controls from separate projects. If I create a user control in the same project it displays properly in the designer. It also seems to only be happening with user controls built for x64. If I build the user controls for x86 and load them into a WPF application built for x86, everything displays properly.

I am running Visual Studio 2019 v 16.2 on Windows 10, using .NET 4.5. My platform target is x64. I am attempting to build the user controls in Class Libraries (.NET Framework) and use them in a WPF App (.NET Framework).

Comment: Finally in VS2022 this is no problem anymore (thanks to its 64 bit design)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Visual Studio problem, which is already known since one year.
No chances or updates.

Comment: Because Visual Studio is a 32 bit application Microsoft has issues displaying 64 bit controls in the designer.  There is talk of making Visual Studio a 64 bit program, but I don't know when that is planned for release.  When I am working with controls, I end up developing in 32 bit.

Comment: it's not a good solution to develop at 32bit only because of the fact, that microsoft don't can bring there application to the standard....

Comment: If you switch to Visual Studio 2022, you get the same basic problem, but it is when you are developing in 32 bit you get the error.  In 64 bit, the designer works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2019:

> you can enable the new WPF .NET Framework designer by checking the “Environment\Preview Features\New WPF XAML Designer for .NET Framework (requires restart)” checkbox in Tools > Options. The new designer has better support for 64-bit projects.

See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-wpf-designer-doesnt-work-with-x64-target/1319945